# Finding an inverse modulo $m$

Tags: modular-arithmetic, inverse

I know that for $m \in \mathbb{Z}$ then $a$ has an inverse modulo $m$ if and only if $\gcd(a,m) = 1$ meaning $a$ and $m$ are relatively prime and their greatest common divisor is 1

Prove that for all integers $n>1$, the number $n-1$ has an inverse modulo $n$.
Thank you

Comment: I feel like I already answered this this morning.

Comment: Hint, $n-1\equiv -1$ modulo $n$.  What's a plausible (multiplicative) inverse for $-1$?

Comment: what factors can $n$ and $n-1$ share?

Answer (score 3):

From the question you wrote, it seems like you *already know* a potential plan to solve this problem: simply prove $\gcd(n-1, n) = 1$.

This works. Do it. (you should have tried it even without the reassurance that it works!)